# Using dhcpcd to reset manually set interface

Tags: dhcp, ubuntu-10.10

1. Use dhcpcd to get IP address (`dhcpcd -p eth0`)
2. Manually change the IP address (`ifconfig eth0 x.x.x.x`)
3. Kill dhcpcd (`dhcpcd -k eth0`)
4. Restart dhcpcd (`dhcpcd -p eth0`)

In this case dhcpcd will not set the IP address of the interface, the interface will come up with the manually set IP address. Why is it not configuring the interface?

`dhcpcd -d eth0` shows:

```
eth0: dhcpcd 4.0.0-beta6 starting
eth0: hardware address = ##:##:##:##:##:##
eth0: broadcasting for a lease
eth0: sending DHCP_DISCOVER with xid 0x25fc838b
eth0: waiting for 3.241 seconds
eth0: offered 192.168.228.180 from 192.168.50.10
eth0: sending DHCP_REQUEST with xid 0x25fc838b
eth0: waiting for 7.224 seconds
eth0: lease of 192.168.228.180 acknowledged
eth0: sending ARP probe #1
eth0: waiting for 1.563 seconds
eth0: sending ARP probe #2
eth0: waiting for 1.442 seconds
eth0: sending ARP probe #3
eth0: waiting for 2.000 seconds
eth0: leased 192.168.228.180 for 691200 seconds
eth0: renew in 345600 seconds
eth0: rebind in 604800 seconds
eth0: adding IP address 192.168.228.180/23
eth0: adding route to 0.0.0.0/0 via 192.168.228.1
eth0: exec `/libexec/dhcpcd-run-hooks'
eth0: forking to background
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that dhcpcd will not configure the interface if the interface has a valid static IP address assigned to it.

By adding a step:
3b. change eth0 IP to an invalid value (ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0)

the interface is configured to the IP address assigned by the DHCP when dhcpcd is restarted.